# py don't reconize ".content", "get_text" and ".strip()" and i install bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I installed bs4 and followed some tutorial about web scraping. I wrote some code but the problem is that python doesn't recognize `.content`, `get_text`, and `.strip()`.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/HP-Pavilion-21-5-Inch-Monitor-22cwa/dp/B015WCV70W/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=screen+hp&qid=1565652560&s=gateway&sr=8-4'

headers = {"user agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
print(title.strip())
```

These are the messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Desktop/python/Webscraper/scrapter.py", line 12, in <module>
    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Desktop/python/Webscraper/scrapter.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(title.strip())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: It recognizes them; but the object returned by the `.find()` method is `None`. Hint: Check your headers.

Comment: Amazon has some restrictions on bots scraping their web. You can check out [this](https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref) for more info about their API

Comment: on some countries it can use JavaScript to add items but BS can't run JavaScript so you may not get expected elements..

Answer (score 0):

It is against Amazon's [terms and conditions](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201909000) to scrape their web.

However, there is an alternative way. What you can do is to register as developer with them [here](https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref) to use their api.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you get these errors because the elements are not found. When you use a beautiful soup method to search for something, and no matches are found;  `None` is returned.